# mouse:down vs. mousedown in fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, mousedown

Here is a fabric.js example with a canvas and a rectangle, with a mouse down handler on each:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var rect = new fabric.Rect({ 
  left: 100, 
  top: 100, 
  width: 50, 
  height: 50, 
  fill: '#faa', 
})

canvas.add(rect);

canvas.on('mouse:down', function(options) {
  console.log('canvas event');
});

rect.on('mousedown', function(options) {
  console.log('rect event');
});
```

Why does it need to be `mouse:down` on the canvas, but `mousedown` on the rectangle? If I change either, they stop working. Is the `mousedown` not actually a fabric event, and if so, should the handler function be different?

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/243kau3x/4/

Answer (score 4):

They are both fabric js events. The main difference is the type of instances to which the events are attached.
 `mouse:down` is a event specific for the fabric Canvas instance while `mousedown` is specific to a fabric Object instance, in your case a rect.

There are different types of events that can be listened on a Canvas and on an Object instance. The full list of available events is available on fabric js official site.

The events specific to the Canvas instance are presented in detail  on the library official GitHub page in this [post](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/Working-with-events).

Comment: Any idea why one has a colon, but not the other?

Comment: For the Canvas they are prefixed with a 'namespace' which gives a logic grouping to the events. You have mouse related events, objects related events etc. On the object on the other hand the events are attached to that particular object so no need for grouping.