# manipulate svg file within a fabric.js canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, fabricjs

I am trying to manipulat an svg file  with fabric.js. I am loading the svg string `fabric.loadSVGFromString` into the canvas correctly. My question is how can I manipulate some parts of the svg.

For example, I imported an electronic breadbord with lot of holes as shown in the pic below [image: electronic board].

How could I detect if a hole has been clicked? How could I get the clicked part?

Thank you

Comment: would you mind posting the svg code? some svg can be imported as ungrouped with little or no problem

Comment: I paste the svg code in this link : http://pastebin.com/0Ly7WiX1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is this:

- first you have to store an array of coords of each hole on your breadboard image
- after you load your background image loop over each entry in that array and create a shape (say, `fabric.Circle`) over the corresponding hole
- right after a shape is created attach a `mousedown` event handler to this shape
- do your click processing in that event handler

Here are a couple of references that can help you with that:

- http://fabricjs.com/per-pixel-drag-drop/
- [mouse:down vs. mousedown in fabric.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32841295/mousedown-vs-mousedown-in-fabric-js)

Comment: Thank you for your replay but i would like to use my svg file not to draw over it, new holes.

Comment: I am loading a svg from string so i hope if there is a way to manipulate the selected paths in this svg

Answer (score 2):

I did a very short demo of what you could do.
The point is create a svg that can be imported as single shapes, lock the shapes on the canvas, then handle click events.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("bb");
svg = '<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny" x="0in" y="0in" width="6.50331in" height="2.1in" viewBox="0 0 468.238 151.2" ><g partID="57380"><g  id="breadboardbreadboard"> <g  id="background">  <rect  fill="#D9D9D9" height="151.199" width="468.238" y="0"/> </g> <g  id="stripes"><rect  fill="#B3B0B0" height="0.4" width="468.238" y="20.932"/>  <rect  fill="#B3B0B0" height="0.4" width="468.238" y="129.475"/> </g> <g >  <rect  fill="#FF0000" height="0.4" width="468.238" y="19.2"/>  <rect  fill="#FF0000" height="0.4" width="468.238" y="148.799"/>  <rect  fill="#0000FF" height="0.4" width="468.238" y="2.4"/>  <rect  fill="#0000FF" height="0.4" width="468.238" y="132"/> </g> <g >  <rect  fill="#CCC9C9" height="7.2" width="468.238" y="71.2"/> </g> <g  id="sockets">  <g  id="pin1A">   <path  fill="#BFBFBF" d="M8.526,115.2c0,-1.322,1.072,-2.394,2.394,-2.394s2.394,1.071,2.394,2.394"/>   <path  fill="#E6E6E6" d="M13.313,115.2c0,1.322,-1.072,2.394,-2.394,2.394s-2.394,-1.071,-2.394,-2.394"/>   <circle  r="1.197" fill="#383838" cx="10.92" cy="115.2"/>  </g>  <g  id="pin1B">   <path  fill="#BFBFBF" d="M8.526,108c0,-1.322,1.072,-2.395,2.394,-2.395s2.394,1.072,2.394,2.395"/>   <path  fill="#E6E6E6" d="M13.313,108c0,1.321,-1.072,2.393,-2.394,2.393S8.526,109.322,8.526,108"/>   <circle  r="1.197" fill="#383838" cx="10.92" cy="108"/>  </g>  <g  id="pin1C">   <path  fill="#BFBFBF" d="M8.526,100.799c0,-1.321,1.072,-2.393,2.394,-2.393s2.394,1.071,2.394,2.393"/>   <path  fill="#E6E6E6" d="M13.313,100.799c0,1.322,-1.072,2.395,-2.394,2.395s-2.394,-1.072,-2.394,-2.395l0,0"/>   <circle  r="1.197" fill="#383838" cx="10.92" cy="100.8"/>  </g></g></g></svg>';


fabric.loadSVGFromString(svg, function(objs) {
  var obj;
  for(var i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
    obj = objs[i];
    obj.lockMovementX = true;
    obj.lockMovementY = true;
    obj.hasControls= false;
    canvas.add(obj);
  }});

canvas.on("object:selected", function(evt) {
  var id = evt.target.id;
  if (id.slice(0,3) == 'pin') {
    alert(id.slice(3,5));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://www.deltalink.it/andreab/fabric/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas width="600" height="400" id="bb" ></canvas>
```